# DBD::mysql for bugzilla installation

Tags: linux, centos, installation, bugzilla

I was installing bugzilla 3.6.3 i have a dependency for DBD::mysql 4.0  currently DBD::mysql installed on the system is 3.0.This is a centos machine  and if any one let me know how to install this DBD::mysql 4 will be pretty useful.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run cpan then install DBD::mysql

`sudo cpan`

`cpan> install DBD::mysql`

you may need to update the whole bundle so substitute `Bundle::DBD::mysql` in the command above.

Comment: cpan> upgrade Bundle::DBD::mysql <br>
Unknown command 'upgrade'. Type ? for help.

Comment: i get the above error

Comment: @Rajeev: sorry I was on the wrong system try install

Comment: i tried it..it has some compilation errors

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.bugzilla.org/docs/3.6/en/html/installation.html and the section "2.1.5. Perl Modules".

The script in the package would make it easier to download and install all Perl modules required.

Comment: Googling this is very easy.Solving this is the problem....